# React Native prevent text from growing container width

Tags: css, react-native

How can I prevent the text from making its container grow in width and instead wrap to keep the width of the container? Note that I don`t want the container to have a fixed width, the width of the container is determined by its other children.

For example, the following code

```
    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={[styles.bubble2, {}]}>
              <View
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: "#ff0000" }}
              />
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                  backgroundColor: "#00ff00"
                }}
              >
                Some random text goes here
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        paddingTop: 20,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      bubble2: {
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }

});
```

renders this. Note how the text makes the container width larger to fit

[image]

and what I am trying to achieve is this without setting the width of the outer container

[image]

Comment: did you solve this? did you use flex?

Comment: try adding  `flexWrap: "wrap" ` to the view container of the text